# Unable to concat many numpy files?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to concatenate many numpy files, For that I use this command, I use cygwin for that:

```
ls | sort --field-separator = --key 2 -h | xargs -rn 4 cat >All_Numpy_Files.npy
```

Let's suppose that I have 100 files, The creation of the final file takes a lot of time, but at the end all what I find in this resulted file is just the first file in the list. 
The shape the resulted file is equal to `1- 800` instead of `100-8000`

Answer (score 1):

`cat >>` will append to already existing file
 `cat  >` will everytime start from scratch and overwrite previous content

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html